# Add a space to the browser-tab title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a robust title for web-crawlers etc... `L.A. Takedown // The Band - bla bla...` ~ but for *style* - I want a cool looking page title. I want the favicon to be the LA *logo*...

I create a new title for the page... *nerd alert*

`var newTitle = '  Takedown';`

Then, inserting it like this...

`document.title = newTitle;`

Then I get this: [image]

I am very pleased with this... but I would love a little space before the 'Takedown' string / which is something I should understand in general...

It seems like strings just do this: http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/YXxyqQ  ( I mean... strip the space at the beginning and end)

But I can add   and replace the spaces for markup... but the `document` / browser tab isn't down with that...

So, why is this string having it's spaces stripped... '__Takedown' - and how can I force a space in there... ??? - in a non-markup situation?

[Here](http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/YXxyqQ) is the CodePen breakdown of the ideas so far... and @moogs idea works in theory --- but the tab still doesn't reflect even though the spaces appear in the `head` as seen here ->

[image]

*If your answer is "the space doesn't matter - it's fine how it is..." or something like that.. just save yourself some time and don't reply. This is just an example.*

This is what I want to happen...
[image]

Comment: One approach to do this is to have the blank space in your icon file.

Comment: @SaeedHamed - That is an approach... but given that I only have a square to work with, and the logo is already wider than it is tall... it would have to become smaller... and - this is all about being a perfectionist... and more about the concept and general understanding of the browser tab limitations - than just making it work on this one site. I want the favicon as big as possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like browsers trim leading white space characters, but the unicode [205f](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/205f/index.htm) medium mathematical space character seems to work:

```
document.title = '​​\u205f​​​ Takedown';
```

Comment: This does the job!  I bet there are a few similar ways - with like-characters:  here's the run-down of the answers:  http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/YXxyqQ

Comment: This works in the CodePen, but not in the browser tab... hmmmmmmm

Comment: You of course don't need the space in the answer, i.e. `​​\u205f​​​Takedown` works fine. (unless you want two spaces, in which it would be `\u205f​​​\u205f​​​Takedown`. Anyway, this solution should be the accepted one, perhaps by adding a list of other acceptable unicode space characters.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the option according to me would be to use `&nbsp;`.

Comment: doesn't work `document.title = '​​&nbsp;&nbsp; Takedown';` changes the title to `​​&nbsp;&nbsp; Takedown`