# Typewriter effect on title tag

Tags: html, css

A while ago, I had seen a website whose title tag had an [animated typewriter effect](https://codepen.io/thiagoteles/pen/ogoxLw) somewhat akin to the one embedded in the hyperlink but instead of being used in the body, it was used on the tab title. I can't remember the website and upon trying it in my case failed. How can it be achieved?

**HTML**

```css
/* Google Fonts */
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anonymous+Pro);

/* Global */
html{
  min-height: 100%;
}
body{
  height: calc(100vh - 8em);
  padding: 4em;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
  font-family: 'Anonymous Pro', monospace;  
  background-color: rgb(25,25,25);  
}
.line-1{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;  
    width: 24em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-right: 2px solid rgba(255,255,255,.75);
    font-size: 180%;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: translateY(-50%);    
}

/* Animation */
.anim-typewriter{
  animation: typewriter 4s steps(44) 1s 1 normal both,
             blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(44) infinite normal;
}
@keyframes typewriter{
  from{width: 0;}
  to{width: 24em;}
}
@keyframes blinkTextCursor{
  from{border-right-color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);}
  to{border-right-color: transparent;}
}
```

```html
<p class="line-1 anim-typewriter">Animation typewriter style using css steps()</p>
<p>
    <b>CSS</b>
</p>
```

Comment: @Spectric I can also use javascript. But how is it achieved anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Promises and `document.title` modification to achieve a typewriter effect on the title.

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
//from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914235/14251221

var str = 'Typewriter-Title';
document.title = '';
async function typewriteTitle() {
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    document.title += str.charAt(i);
    console.log(document.title); //debug only
    await sleep(200);
  }
}
typewriteTitle();
```

Note: Running it in the snippet won't do anything - it's sandboxed.

Here's the result:

[image: Title-Typewriter-Effect]

Comment: Trying it on my end shows the chars added at uneven intervals and removes whitespaces. Why?

Comment: @user14773854 Maybe your browser can't keep up with the short delay? Try changing `await sleep(200);` to `await sleep(500);`.

Comment: What of the whitespaces?

Comment: @user14773854 Unfortunately, browsers strip out leading/ending spaces in the title. I recommend using a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30833402/add-a-space-to-the-browser-tab-title)

Comment: 250ms works well for me as a delay. Perhaps you can change it.